# Using JQuery and AJAX to pass data to a PHP script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have an HTML form that Is only composed of a button with a value. I would like to leave it this way. I am using AJAX/JQuery to pass the form data to a PHP script. But, for some reason, the button value is not sent. What could I be doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<form id="friend-send" method="post" action="">
<button type="submit" class="foll" name="approve-friend" value="4"> Approve </button>
</form>
```

AJAX/JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#friend-send").submit(function(e) {

        var $this = $(this);        
        var dataString = $this.serialize(); 

        e.preventDefault();     

        $.ajax({  
            type: "POST",  
            url: "relate.php",  
            data: dataString,
            async: false,
            success: function() {
                $this.hide();
            }
        });             

    });

});
```

Comment: Where is `friend-request-buttons` in your HTML?

Answer (score 3):

JQuery won't serialize a button, use a hidden field instead

```
 <form id="friend-send" method="post" action="">
 <input type="hidden" name="approve-friend" value="4" />
 <button type="submit" class="foll"> Approve </button>
 </form>
```

Also, You need to serialze the form by id, not the button by id
Instead of this

```
 $("#friend-request-buttons")
```

It should be this

```
 $("#friend-send")
```

Lastly, since you are using ajax to post, you can simplfy your form open tag to this...

```
 <form id="friend-send">
```

Comment: Well in my PHP script I make sure that the submit button is set, to make sure that the script only be ran if the user actually submitted the form. Will using a hidden form be as secure? Thanks.

Comment: a hidden input element, not a form.  You still keep the submit button.

Comment: Like @thescientist said, its just a hidden input element

Comment: I know, but if the submit button is not passed via JQuery, then it will always not be set.

Comment: Couldn't someone edit the form in an inspector and change the value of the hidden input even if it is static?

Comment: no one is saying anything about changing the button.

Comment: you could add the readonly attribute.  but I don't think it would make a difference, hidden or not whether someone could live edit the code.  That's why you always validate on the server side.

Comment: If you want to go the button route, then don't serialize.

Answer (score 1):

`<button>`
tags are not supported by serialize https://api.jquery.com/serialize/

You would need to use an input of some kind.  A hidden one would work.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `serialize`, create the input data yourself:

```
var dataString = {};
var $button = $this.find("[type=submit]");
dataString[$button.attr('name')] = $button.val();
```

When you provide an object as the `data:` argument to `$.ajax`, jQuery will serialize it automatically.

Comment: Can you explain what is happening on the last line of your answer? And also the `{}` on the first line? As you can see in my answer below I am just building the dataString very archaically :/

Answer (score 0):

This answer would be if you are set on using the button alone

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#friend-send").submit(function(e) {

    var $this = $(this);        
    var dataString = "?" + $(this).find('button').attr('name') + "=" + $(this).find('button').attr('value'); 

    e.preventDefault();     

    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "relate.php",  
        data: dataString,
        async: false,
        success: function() {
            $this.hide();
        }
    });             

    });

});
```